# How do Node.js and Laravel fit together

Tags: node.js, laravel

I'm doing the courses at Laracasts and the command npm install && npm run dev is used. This didnt work from my htdocs/projectname directory so I installed the windows 10 node.js installer, which installed it to a program files directory.
Somehow, it seems node.js ended up in my packages.json

Node.js seems to be all javascript on the server side? How does this work with Laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS can be used for many things, which include server-side code, as well as provides tools to be used in a development environment, which are available through the NPM Repository. A quote from the NodeJS Wikipedia page states the following:

> Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform, back-end, JavaScript
> runtime environment that executes JavaScript code outside a web
> browser.

A standard Laravel installation includes a package.json file as standard, which includes the commands and requirements for various packages, one of which includes laravel-mix, which is a webpack based tool for optimizing and compiling your assets (Typically Stylesheets and Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

NPM ist the Node package manager. It's installed with Node.js.
You can use `npm -v` in the CLI to check if it's installed correctly.
In your project directory must be a package.json to use `npm install` && `npm run dev`.
In case of Laravel a package.json should be in the directory.